# How to override Drupal 8 dompdf dpi?

Tags: pdf, drupal-8

I am using entityprint with dompdf engine.
Per default there ist defined 96dpi for pdf's.
But I would like to get 300 dpi.
The Variable is set here:
\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Options.php
with

```
  private $dpi = 300;
```

What is the right way to override this variable programmaticaly?
Is it possible?

Comment: which module do you use to generate the pdf?  or your own custom module?

Comment: I am using https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print